# How do I fix python ursina error in voxel game

Tags: python, voxel, ursina

*In my python project I get an error like this:*

package_folder: C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina
asset_folder: e:\Dimiland\Programiranje\Python\Visual Studio Code\Games
screen resolution: (1440, 900)
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.**del** at 0x00000249051B55A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 186, in **del**
del self._cached_image
AttributeError: _cached_image
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\Dimiland\Programiranje\Python\Visual Studio Code\Games\Game 01.py", line 24, in 
player = FirstPersonController()
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\prefabs\first_person_controller.py", line 32, in **init**
ray = raycast(self.world_position+(0,self.height,0), self.down, ignore=(self,))
File "C:\Users\POM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ursina\entity.py", line 425, in world_position
return Vec3(self.get_position(render))
NameError: name 'render' is not defined

*This is my code:*

```
    from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina

class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            position = position,
            model = 'cube',
            texture = 'white_cube',
            color = color.white,
            highlight_color = color.lime,
            origin_y = 0.5,
            scale = 0.5
            )

for z in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        voxel = Voxel(position = (x,0,z))


player = FirstPersonController()

voxel = Voxel()

app.run
```

**HOW TO FIX THIS??>**

Comment: You need to take us to your **entity.py** file and tell us what is in there. I think that is where your error is coming from.

Comment: In the next question, please provide the minimal reproducable example and format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `()`.

`app = Ursina` should be `app = Ursina()`.

Comment: Ohh, tnx. I’m stupid kid

Comment: And app.run should be app.run()